# Override class in ActiveAdmin index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am  using [ActiveAdmin Flat Skin](https://github.com/ayann/active_admin_flat_skin) as template and I want to highlight some rows of the index page depending on an attribute of the row. The index page shows `even` `odd` rows displaying even rows with a light gray. Depending on this `available` attribute I want to display them with a light red.

I got the following partially working:

```
index  row_class: ->elem { 'red' unless elem.available } do |dog|
```

In my active_admin.scss I have the following

```
.red {
  background-color: #f7b9b9 !important;
}
```

But the rows that have the light gray are not being displayed in red. Any ideas?

Here is how it looks right now. The ones that say "[NO EN ADOPCION]" should all be in red.

[image]

Even if I inspect the element and add an inline `style="background-color: red !important"` the background does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the css to:

```
tr.odd, tr.even {
  &.red {
    background-color: #f7b9b9 !important;
  }
}
```